# Is there any explanation for how Akihiko Kayaba managed to trap everyone in SAO?

Tags: sword-art-online

It seems farfetched that Akihiko Kayaba would be able to sneak in all that malicious code into Sword Art Online without anyone knowing. Surely it would have been a big project with many developers. Furthermore, it seems like it would be difficult for him stop the other developers from fixing Sword Art Online. Even if he destroyed the source code or something, they still had a whole year to figure something out. Do the light novels shed any more light on Kayaba's scheme?

Comment: Doesn't seem farfetched when you remember that Akihiko Kayaba is the inventor of the NervGear and creator of SAO and being the guy at the very top of both of them he can easily slip code/functionality in after QA

Comment: This big thing to worry about here is the hardware - software is of secondary importance.

Comment: SAO Abridged gives a really good explanation for this.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser Link please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've read the Light Novels and it doesn't really cover any more than the anime on how he managed it. And in all honesty, its entirely possible that he was able to slip all that coding in. My father is a programmer so I have a rough idea on how much code goes into a lot of projects and there are actually very few times that people get to view the code as a whole, with each person or group working a small part and then sending it in to add to the bigger project. With this knowledge in hand, being able to work that much code in wouldn't be too far fetched even if Kayaba wasn't top dog, but since he is it is very conceivable that it could happen.

Comment: Cyberson, do you disagree with  Clockwork-Muse who said 'This big thing to worry about here is the hardware - software is of secondary importance' ? Happy Easter!

Answer (score 2):

Since Kayaba is known as someone with a high position for the development of the game and the NerveGear, he's probably highly involved with the development and he could have had some backdoor program or an admin level access to the system.

That way he can just remove the Logout option in the database as well as overwrite the program on the nervegear (as it's also connected to the internet via the pc) to fry the player's brain when attempted to be taken off (assuming he hid an extra "feature" in the hardware design that of the nerve gear that could amplify the voltage/ampere).

Comment: This is more of a personal opinion than an answer. Please support what you are saying.

Comment: @Tamz_m Cyberson answered that light novels doesn't have details on how Kayaba initiated his plan. My answer is an assumption, as a software developer, of what Kayaba could have pulled off assuming he has direct involvement with the development of the NerveGear and SAO system

Comment: @ Bahamut - I think you need to read the sites guidelines for answering questions. Questions for a start are not allowed to be asked if the answers are opinion based, therefore the answers also should not be just an opinion. Opinions should be in comments. If you are going to post opinions use links from external sites to support them/back them up.

Comment: Bahamut well...any external site to support re what @Tamz_m said?